# Silex route match all, also /

Tags: routes, silex

using this code i get `No route found for "GET /"` when i point to homepage

```
$app->match('{url}', function($url) use($app) {


})->method('GET|POST')->assert('url', '.+');
```

There is a regex or something to match also the / ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but this may work :

```
$app->match('/{url}', function($url) use($app) {


})
->method('GET|POST')
->assert('url', '.+')
->value('url', '');
```

Comment: Works perfectly!